# Spring Data REST generating link for embedded collection incorrectly

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a case where SPR is generating links for an embedded collection that is an attribute of my Entity when it should not. I have the following class structure. I'm using Lombok to generate the various getter/setters as well, but I don't think that matters.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Person
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
   private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Address
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String street;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String zip;

   @ManyToOne
   private Person person;
}
```

Everything compiles, and when I get the JSON output from SDR for one of the Persons, I get the following in the links section.

```
"_links" : {
  "self" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
  },
  "person" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1/person"
  }
}
```

Trying to access this `/people/1/person` link fails with a 404, as I would expect. I've confirmed that it is coming from the `addresses` collection on the `Person` object. But I cannot figure out why it is there and how to remove it.

There is no `Repository` for the `Address` class of Entities, as they are exclusively child entities of the `Person` object. Maybe I'm modeling this wrong in the Object tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue. I think I resolved this by updating to Spring HATEOAS 0.17.0, but I'm not sure. I was working on a number of issues at the same time, and had put this issue on the back burner for a bit and now everything is working.